# Get random row without duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have this table `Questions`:

```
questionid  question                         duplicateid
-----------------------------------------------------
    1       1. How are you feeling today?    NULL
    2       2. How are you today?            1
    3       3. What is your interest?        NULL
    4       4. What are your hobbies?        3
    5       5. Which is your birthplace?     NULL
    6       6. Where were you born?          5
    7       7. What are you doing this weekend?     NULL
    8       8. Any plans for the weekend?    7
    9       9. How old are you?              NULL
   10      10. What is your age?             9
   11      11. Tell me something about yourself!    NULL
   12      12. Can you brief me about yourself!     11
   13      13. What is your Name?            NULL
   14      14. May I know your Good Name?    13
```

I have tried below to 5 question... means I need only 5 answers to list from query.

```
SELECT TOP 5 NEWID(), * 
FROM Questions
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Here my question is, I need 5 random question.. and condition is let say two questions are same "Which is your birthplace?" and "Where were you born?", this is managed through `duplicateid` column of table, means questionID 6 is duplicate of q5.

In output I need 5 records random, but any one from dupldate (example questionID 5 or question 6, but not both), if I run query again, in this way set questions in table.

Can you please give suggestion on this how we can do this random 5 but anyone from duplicate if any duplicate comes in result?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam - which version of SQL Server are you **really** using? Please tag only one version - thank you

Comment: I've removing your conflicting version tags... please add the correct one.

Comment: I used sql-server 2019

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using sql server

```
SELECT TOP 5 RAND() as RandomValue, * 
FROM Questions
ORDER BY RandomValue
```

Comment: I have tried, but in my case duplicate question , with questionid and duplidateid only 1 should be there, in this case sometimes both are coming in result... because such dupliatcate question are same meaning, so in result set anyone can be there its OK... let say 5. Which is your birthplace?
6. Where were you born?     this two are same... anyone can be there in result set on top 5 ,should NOT be both... and duplicate check I Have manage through questionid and duplicateid from my schema.  .can you please help on this

Comment: Cant you do Distinct Quetion ?